# Restrict tables in DB, on which a user can run queries in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am making an app with Laravel which has "service" tables like users, items, user_items and so on.

Also, I have tables on which I need to allow users to run their queries. That is, a user send his query to a server and it is run there.

The problem is: I want to allow a user to run only SELECT queries and forbid to run UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE. 
Also, I need to allow to run these queries only on definite tables. That is, a user is not allowed to select from users table.

Users will run raw queries, that is DB:raw() will be used.

How can I do that in Laravel?

One of the solutions is to make two databases: MYSQL and sqlite and allow users to use only sqlite for running queries, but there will be a problem with testing in this case.

Comment: Did you mean, some users are allowed to use tables and some users are not?

Comment: No. All users of my app will be allowed to send their own queries to the app. It will be an app that will check if a user made right query for a task. E.g., a user will have a task to select goods from a table. He will send query "SELECT * FROM goods" and the server will check if it was done right.

Comment: First check if user has a permission to use this functionality and then execute query. How can you execute query and then check if user has a permission to use this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of the [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) and REVOKE commands. First create the user as outlined in the documents

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT SELECT ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

Then revoke the excess one by one

```
REVOKE SELECT ON db1.tablename FROM 'jeffrey'@'localhost'
```

you will have to do this on each table. So one option is to write a PHP script that does it in a loop

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to do it programatically without changing database.

Comment: That's not possible and this the proper way to do it. This is a solved problem. Besides how do you prevent someone using the same username and password to make changes to the database using the console and by passing laravel?